# is it possible to find the file which contains a specific text in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

Consider this situation where i have many files under a folder "Example".And if i need to find a file which contains a specific phrase like "Class Example", how do i do it with a linux shell?

is there any "locate" like functions in linux to do this?

Thanks,

Balan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use good ol' `grep`:

```
grep -R "Class Example" Example
```

where `"Class Example"` is the search string and `Example` is the directory, and `-R` specifies recursive search.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
find Example | xargs grep 'Class Example'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using   egrep "text1|text2" *
or using grep,
and cscope is also a good tool for searching and editing..

Answer (score 0):

If you want a gui, and/or fast results,Beagle is a nice solution that I use.  [Beagle Main Page.](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page)

Comment: What is this Beagle? how does this relates to my question?

Comment: @balanv Beagle is a search daemon for Linux. I use it in Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

### List of file names containing a given text

You can use a combination of `find` with `grep` to find the list of filenames containing the text as below.

```
find /<path>/Example -name "*" -exec grep -l "Class Example" {} \;
```

Even if you are not use about the case like "Class" vs "class", you can use the `-i` switch to ignore case. Also if you know the file extension, you can give that to the `-name` attribute. You can read further details [here](http://www.digizol.com/2010/10/linux-find-content-filenames-search.html).