# Linux Command: Find string in files content

Tags: linux, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to find the file which contains a specific text in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762611/is-it-possible-to-find-the-file-which-contains-a-specific-text-in-linux)

I want to find where a string occurs in a file directory by command line in Linux.
 For example, I want to find where the string "isOutOfCircle()" occurs in files belonging "My Project" directory. How to do this?

Comment: you mean like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762611/is-it-possible-to-find-the-file-which-contains-a-specific-text-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -R 'isOutOfCircle()' "My Project"`

`-R` is for recursion search. You may want `man grep` for more details.